# Object created without keyword new out of scope within main function

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes, new-operator

I am attempting to implement a linked list in C++, when I create an object pointer without the keyword new, the code does not display anything. I have done some research and found that by using the new keyword this fixed this issue, but I am not entirely sure as to why this fixes it, I read that the pointer object may go out of scope and this "new" prevents that, but I do not understand how it goes out of scope.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
   int val;
};

int main(){
    Node *head;
    //Node *head = new Node; fixed the issue
    head->val = 200;
    cout << head->val;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No object is created at all until you use `new()` in this code, so the question itself is incorrect. `head` is a pointer to a *potential* object, not a pointer to an object all the time.

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `head`. You are confusing a pointer with an object that it points to (or, in this case, doesn't point to any valid object). Your favorite C++ textbook should have a section on pointers; you may wish to review it.